# How to get the exact row number in dataframe in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

How can I get the exact row number in a dataframe that contains a certain value in a certain column using Panda? For example, I have the following dataframe:

```
    Date       Amount    Merchant
0   3/4/2020   2367.25   Apple
1   3/5/2020   625.09    Best Buy
2   3/6/2020   4.99      Pandora
3   3/7/2020   68.26     Amazon
```

The code I have so far iterates through the merchant column and looks in my dictionary where each merchant is the key and the value is a list with a general ledger code and a general ledger description.

My problem is that certain Merchants can have 2 GL codes depending on the item bought, generally anything over a 1000 dollars will get assigned a different GL code than what is typically assigned for anything under a thousand.

As the program iterates through it will reach a merchant that has 2 possible GL codes, all merchants that are special are in a list called SpecialMerchants. All I have is the merchant name from the csv file, how can I use that to locate the row number that, that merchant is on and match it up with the Amount column.

```
for i in df['Merchant']:
    for key in DicOfGLs:
        if key in i:
            for SpecialKey in SpecialMerchants:
                if SpecialKey == key:
                    print(df.loc[i])
                    if ExpenseDF['Amount'] > 1000.00:
                        df[key] = pd.Series([df[key][1][0]])
                        df[key] = pd.Series([df[key][1][1]])
                    else:
                        df[key] = pd.Series([df[key][0][0]])
                        df[key] = pd.Series([df[key][0][1]])
                else:
                    df['GL Code'] = pd.Series([df[key][0]])
                    df['GL Description'] = pd.Series([df[key][1]])
```

Heres a snippet of some of the GL codes and descriptions and the list of special Merchants

```
DicOfGLs = {
    'BESTBUY': {0: ['760.6500.00', 'IT SUPPLIES'], 1: ['760.7110.00', 'IT COMPUTER EXPENSE']},
    'APPLE': {0: ['760.6500.00', 'IT SUPPLIES'], 1: ['760.7110.00', 'IT COMPUTER EXPENSE']},
    'MICROSOFT': ['760.7100.00', 'SOFTWARE']
}

SpecialMerchants = [
    'BESTBUY',
    'APPLE',
    'APPLE STORE',
    'MICROCENTER',
    'Amazon.com',
    'AMZN MKTP US*'
    ]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow! Your question is bit ambiguous. Do you want to know the row number of merchant if you filter on amount from ExpenseDF and Merchant name from SpecialMerchants?

Comment: Thanks! So I want to know what the exact row number the Merchant is on so I can use that to match up with the correct amount and compare it to 1000 in the if statement. basically, if the Merchant charge is over a thousand assign a certain GL code and if it's under assign another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the index of the merchant DataFrame.index can be used. Here is the example.The contents of the file is same as you have given in the question.

```
file = pd.read_csv("Documents\check.csv")

SpecialMerchants = [
'BESTBUY',
'APPLE',
'APPLE STORE',
'MICROCENTER',
'Amazon.com',
'AMZN MKTP US*'
]

for i in file.Merchant:
if i.upper() in SpecialMerchants:
   print(file[file.Merchant == i].index[0])


Output: 0
```

The index will return a tuple giving you the index of the row in which that merchant is present along with the data type of the index. So to only get the index value I have added index[0].

```
 file[file.Merchant == "Apple"].index
 Output:Int64Index([0], dtype='int64')
```